# How many downloads are applicable thru universal link in ios In-house-distribution?

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution, ios-universal-links

I've successfully distributed my app throw universal(In-house-distribution) link and people are started downloading my app for crowd testing.

I'm wondering how many users can download the app throw external(universal) link.

Is there any restriction/limitation apple has to download the app? or Any max number applicable to download? If so, how many number can download and how the Apple will identify number of downloads happened?

It would be great if anyone share your experience on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have an enterprise developer program membership then there is no limit to the number of times it can be installed

Comment: Awesome! thanks for your information @Paulw11.